# Python is not working in ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, python

I am getting the error:

```
The program 'python' is not installed.  
You can install it by typing:  
sudo apt-get install python-minimal
```

I have done this and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Please be more specific. The python system definitely works fine in 14.04. Are you using some PPAs that provide python packages? Did you modify the alternatives system?

Comment: What is the output of the command to install python? Run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall python` and update your question with the output ([edit] it, don't write comments or answers to provide additional information!)

Answer (score -3):

You can install anaconda package in ubuntu following this [instruction](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install#linux-install).In that way along with python you will get other mostly used python packages as well.

Or you can install the basic python following these instructions

First install dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall
sudo apt-get install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev
```

Then download the latest version

```
wget http://python.org/ftp/python/2.7.9/Python-2.7.9.tgz
```

Extract and go to the dirctory

```
tar -xvf Python-2.7.9.tgz
cd Python-2.7.9
```

Then install using following commands

```
./configure
make
sudo checkinstall
```

Comment: I'm new to SO,can anyone enlighten what's wrong with my answer?